# need help implementing this "when the numbers are between 10 and 5

Tags: python

implement a program that prints a range of 100 numbers and prints a different message when the numbers are smaller than 10, another message when the numbers are between 10 and 50, and another message when the numbers are greater than 50.

I need some help with the second part of the condition.

This is what i have so far.

```
for i in range(100):
    if i <10:
        print("The following number is less than 10")
    if i <= 50:
        print(" The following number is in between 10 and 50")
    else: 
        print("The following number is greater than 50 ")
    print(i)
```

Comment: change your `if i <= 50:` to `elif i <= 50:`

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax

```
elif 10 <= i <= 50:
        print(" The following number is in between 10 and 50")
```

Comment: You could also omit the `10 <=` part, because it is already covered by the `if`-`elif` construction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `elif`. The `elif` statement is only executed if the previous `if` condition evaluates to false (so the if block is not executed) and the condition in the `elif` evaluates to true.

```
for i in range(100):
    if i<10:
        print("the following number is less than 10")
    elif i<=50:
        print("the following number is is between 10 and 50")
    else:
        print("the number is greater than 50")
```